# How can I know which PDB file contains type information for a given struct?

Tags: windows, debugging, winapi, debug-symbols

I'm translating some Windows header files to Delphi. In order to verify alignment of related C structs, I need to dump certain PDB files to see the associated type information. To do this, I tried to use [PdbXtract](https://www.mandiant.com/blog/archives/2512), but this tool asks me to select a PDB file to inspect. How do I know which PDB file contains the desired struct definition?

Comment: Do you really have so many candidates that you can't just try all of them until you find the one you need?

Comment: @Rob, maybe I can do some guessings, but it seems not a smart way, and it can be painful to translate non-specific headers such as `WinNT.h`. I just hope there is an easier way to do this.

Comment: Why are you translating WinNT.h when there are already translations available from Embarcadero and Project JEDI? Another technique: Compile a test program in C that prints out the details about the types you're interested in. Usually, just `sizeof` is sufficient. Incidentally, the PDB of *that* program would contain the information you need, too.

Comment: @Rob, I said "such as". However, indeed, I translated some `WinNT.h` structs introduced in newer versions of Windows such as TOKEN_USER_CLAIMS etc. which was not translated by Embarcadero.

Comment: I'll be glad if I can inspect the interested struct without having to use MSVC++. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigating PDB files using hex editor, I figure out to know which PDB file contains the desired struct definition, by using a *grep-like* tool to search for PDB filenames containing the following regex pattern:

```
\x15\x00\x00\x80\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00_Struct_Name\x00
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the strings.exe command line utility from SysInternals (now MS). I ran the following `strings -s . | findstr /i critical_section` in my symbols folder and got a lot of interesting output:

`C:\debuggers-v6.12.2.633-x86\sym\verifier.pdb\8878279C450C4F4DA6B252A4B824B4981\verifier.pdb: _RTL_CRITICAL_SECTION
C:\debuggers-v6.12.2.633-x86\sym\verifier.pdb\8878279C450C4F4DA6B252A4B824B4981\verifier.pdb: U_RTL_CRITICAL_SECTION@@
C:\debuggers-v6.12.2.633-x86\sym\wntdll.pdb\B193CACD9AB340E7BF3434EA1ABBE0482\wntdll.pdb: _RTL_CRITICAL_SECTION
C:\debuggers-v6.12.2.633-x86\sym\wntdll.pdb\B193CACD9AB340E7BF3434EA1ABBE0482\wntdll.pdb: U_RTL_CRITICAL_SECTION@@
C:\debuggers-v6.12.2.633-x86\sym\wntdll.pdb\B193CACD9AB340E7BF3434EA1ABBE0482\wntdll.pdb: _RTL_CRITICAL_SECTION_DEBUG`

Comment: @Marc_Sherman, +1 for inspiring me to found a better solution. :-)